# Pdfkit python css not working as expected on aws ec2 server

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

I am using pdfkit python 0.6.1 with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 on both my local system and on ec2 server
The Problem is everything is running as expected on local system but on aws css styling got changed

Here is the template code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pdf Generate html</title>
    <style>
     @font-face {
      font-family: 'BoldFont';
      src: url('http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/fonts/Champagne & Limousines Bold.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center ;font-family: 'BoldFont' ;line-height:30.5pt;position:absolute;  margin:80px 72px; letter-spacing:0.275em;line-height: 1.7;  text-transform: uppercase;">

<div id="svg_view" style="border: 7px solid #000; ">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/svg_img/test.svg" style="padding:75px">

        <div class="product-des" id="product-header" style="font-size: 22.5pt;letter-spacing:0.281em; margin-top:-8px;">UNDER THESE STARS YOU WERE BORN<br>
            LOVE YOU TO THE MOON AND BEYOND</div>
    <div class="name" id="user_name" style=" font-size: 19.8pt; margin:115px 0px 134px 0">{{username}}</div>
    <div class="product-des" id="product-des" style=" font-size: 15pt;margin-bottom:50px;letter-spacing:0.22em">
        THE SKIES ABOVE Hadera, Israel<br> {{mth}} {{day}}th, {{year}} AT {{hrs}}:{{min}} AM<br> {{lat}}˚ N <span style="margin-left:18px">{{long}}˚ E</span>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is python code

```
 template_name = "site/pdf_generate.html"

    def get(self, request):
        options = {
            'page-size': 'A3',
            'margin-top': '0',
            'margin-right': '0',
            'margin-bottom': '0',
            'margin-left': '0',
            'dpi': 300
        }
        context = {
            'username':request.session.get("myname"),
            'lat': request.session.get("lat"),
            'long': request.session.get("long"),
            'msg': request.session.get("msg"),
            'mth': request.session.get("mth"),
            'day': request.session.get("day"),
            'year': request.session.get("year"),
            'hrs': request.session.get("hrs"),
            'min': request.session.get("min"),

        }

        file_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_DIR, "pdf", 'dpi_test123.pdf')
        svg_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_DIR,"images/svg_img/d3-celestial.svg")

        template = loader.get_template(self.template_name)
        html_string = template.render(context=context, request=request)
        try:
            pdfkit.from_string(html_string, file_path,options=options)
        except:
            print("Error found")
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            response = FileResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'), content_type='application/force-download')
            return response
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong")
```

Local System as expected
[image]

Aws ec2 not working good
[image]